# Determining the probability for accuracy when trying to approximate a ratio

Tags: probability

Given a string of ones and  zeros of length $n$ (bit string, just for simplification, the zeros and ones could represent any problem with two possible states) I want to approximate the ration of ones and zeros. How can I compute the probability, that my approximation lies in a $\epsilon-$radius of the actual ratio, given that I can only choose a constant number of samples from the bit string, independent of how large $n$ is (meaning thee number of samples chosen should not depend on $n$). However, I'm allowed to repeat this procedure for a constant number of times, which should also not depend on $n$. How could I proceed?

Comment: Does that mean there are $k$ and $r$ such that you can "measure" the number of ones in $r$ subsets of size $k$, and these subsets are independently and uniformly randomly picked from the $n\choose k$ possible such subsets?

Comment: When making your guess for the approximation, are you given only the $r$ sample results, or do you also know $n$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes,

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I also know $n$, but my solution should be valid for all $n$, meaning it should require constant time and not $O(n)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen do you have any idea how I could proceed?